# Is the amulet of articulation the only armored necklace in the game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I received the amulet of articulation when I became Guild Master and was pleasantly surprised to see that it was armored (9 points is a good rating when it could have been 0!) in addition to having a kicka** enchantment on it.

However, during fights, I like to change my armor to something stronger, and I would like to know if there's an available enchant-able armored necklace anywhere else in the game. I found the ancient nord amulet in the Jarl's longhouse in Falkreath, but it neither had any armor points nor was it enchant-able...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are no other armoured necklaces in the game. You can however use enchanting to get what you need but I'm not sure that this is what you're looking for.

You can use Fortify Armor on any necklace you find, [**this**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects#Apparel_Effects) page lists what enchantments are useable on various body parts. You will not be able to re-enchant an already enchanted item though. The Ancient Nord Amulet should be enchant-able since it it not already enchanted however is it classified as a speciality item which could be why it isn't working.

[**This**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unique_Items) page lists all the unique items available in the game including all Amulets/Necklaces. The Amulet of Articulation is the only amulet on the list with an armor rating.

There is however the Mage's Circlet which is obtained during the College of Winterhold quest Good Intentions. According to [**this**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveled_Items) (bottom of the page) it has a rather good armor rating.

Answer (score 2):

Locket of Saint Jiub.  Armor 9 for light.  Enchantment present however, carrying and stamina increase 50.

Comment: Link for the locket:  https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Locket_of_Saint_Jiub  Base game, the locket cannot be improved despite being light armor.  The USEP feels this is a bug and has fixed it:  https://afktrack.afkmods.com/index.php?a=issues&i=11978

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any other armoured necklaces, but if you have an enchanting skill of 100 you can replicate one by using dual enchantment - put a Fortify Armour enchantment on the necklace plus whatever other enchantment you want.